# How to get response for accepted app request in facebook android..?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

If User 'A' sent's App request to User 'B' in facebook, now how to get the result of that request to A whether B as accepted or reject ..?

If it is a android app installation request , now how to know that user accepted and installed
the app. Is there any api to know what happened to that particular request...?

Please help me out..

Thanks in advance ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FB doesn't tell you if the request was accepted.

When user B "accepts" the request they will be directed to your app (mobile or canvas), you can query for all the requests for user B, and then notify user A (you should also delete the request).

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0#reading